# Meteor Mobile need double click to make it work

Tags: angularjs, meteor, ionic-framework, angular-meteor

all. I need a help about the mobile app. So I follow the 'todos list' tutorial of meteor angular 1, and build an simple mobile app with ionic framework. But I need to click the button or tabs twice in order to make it work. How to solve this twice clicking issue?

```
<ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-top tabs-positive">
  <ion-tab title="Home" icon="ion-home" ui-sref="tabs.home">
    <ion-nav-view name="home-tab"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>
  <ion-tab title="About" icon="ion-ios-football" ui-sref="tabs.about">
    <ion-nav-view name="about-tab"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>
  <ion-tab title="Contact" icon="ion-bag" ui-sref="tabs.contact">
    <ion-nav-view name="contact-tab"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>
  </ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

So these are basically the code from ionic, but I need to click a button twice like 'About' button to change the state to state 'about'. And I'm using angular 1, anybody have similar problems before?

Comment: Is it anything to do with hammerjs? http://hammerjs.github.io/

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to this issue. https://github.com/Urigo/meteor-ionic/issues/30

Removing the mobile-experience package should fix the problem.

From ionic docs:

> Out of the box, Ionic automatically removes the 300ms delay in order
>   to make Ionic apps feel more “native” like. Resultingly, other
>   solutions such as fastclick and Angular’s ngTouch should not be
>   included, to avoid conflicts.

Remove mobile-experience and add again the mobile-status-bar and launch-screen.